# Strange rendering issue with Java Swing libaray

Tags: java, swing, user-interface

**Background**
I want to create a GUI application using the [java swing](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/package-summary.html) library. For layout I require it to be a GridLayout as the program outline requires this.

**Aim**
To render a panel with text inside it.

**What I have tired**

- Using setBounds to move the text - this worked and the text did render, however it does not work with the GridLayout therefore does not meet the required specs.
- Reading atricles and documentation on GridLayout and rendering of JLabels - Tried the examples - failed.
- Using intellij debugger - results show the JLabel is not null, and the text is set to the correct value, along with the enabled and visible properties being true.
- Increasing and decreasing GirdLayout rows and columns - failed.
- Altering the size of the panel - failed.
- Changing the foreground colour to something like green - failed.

**Code**

```java
public class MainPanel extends JPanel {
    public MainPanel(JFrame frame) {
        setBounds(40,40,200,200);
        setBackground(Color.BLUE);

        JLabel label = new JLabel("Hello World", SwingConstants.CENTER);
        label.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.PLAIN, 25));
        label.setVisible(true);
        add(label);

        setLayout(new GridLayout(1, 1));
    }

}
```

**Result**
[image]

**Conclusion**
As you can see, the panel does render (the blue square), however there is no text inside of it. I'm rather confused as code very similar to this has worked on aother project, and there is no obvious reason this shouldn't work.

Comment: Why do you pass `frame`? It's not used... It's generally tricky to advise as you haven't shown the context of the use of your `JPanel` subclass. You should call `setLayout` *before* adding components

Comment: @g00se It was for testing, there is no need for it I just forgot to remove it, and I know, I could have just passed in the data that I needed at the time instead of the entire frame, but it was quicker and easier, it's not going into production - from the examples I found it was always at the bottom, I've moved it up, as it makes more sense, thank you, however it does not fix the issue at hand

Answer (score 0):

Your code is essentially OK with the provisos I mentioned. Proof: (obviously you can separate out your own class as a top level one later):

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.SwingConstants;


public class F extends JFrame {
    private void setGui() {
        try {
            setLocation(0, 100);
            setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
            setContentPane(new MainPanel());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            EventQueue.invokeAndWait(() -> {
                F f = new F();
                f.setGui();
                f.setSize(200, 200);
                f.setVisible(true);
            });
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
class MainPanel extends JPanel {
    public MainPanel() {
        setLayout(new GridLayout(1, 1));
        setBounds(40,40,200,200);
        setBackground(Color.BLUE);
        JLabel label = new JLabel("Hello World", SwingConstants.CENTER);
        label.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.PLAIN, 25));
        add(label);
    }

}
```

Comment: Yes, I'm glad you mentioned that. I should have mentioned it. I really left that in to 'prove' the original code worked